# Replace any line breaks where this is more than one with a single

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, preg-replace, str-replace

Im using CKEditor and users copy and paste content into it.

When saving this data ckeditor normally makes two line breaks but sometimes they can paste 3 or 4 etc.

These line breaks are different between users e.g.:

```
<br> <br /> <br/>
```

What i want to do is replace any amount of consecutive line breaks with just a single?

So if there is more than 2 together, replace with one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/(<br\ ?\/?>)+/", '<br />', $text);
```

Comment: Perfect. Was already using nl2br in my function so just replaced all consecutive breaks with a blank. Thanks.